# Field Calculator in Graphical Modeller always returns 0 or NULL

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, qgis-modeler

I made a simple graphical model:

A Vector Layer input with a corresponding Vector Field `vf` input. A Field Calculator is used to calculate a new field's value based on the selected Vector Field's value of each feature using the expression

```
CASE
  WHEN @vf = 'foo' THEN 1 
  ELSE 0
END
```

The user is supposed to pick a layer and a field of that layer. A new "boolean" integer field is calculated then, set to 1 if the selected field matches a certain condition and 0 if not.

I always get a `0` as result. It also does not work if I use a `if()` function instead of the `CASE` statement. It also does not work if I surround the `@vf` with double quotes: `WHEN "@vf" ...`

It works if I reproduce the same workflow manually without a model, substituting the `@vf` in the expression with the actual field name of course.

How can I get this seemingly simple Field Calculator expression to work correctly?

Comment: If Vector Field is a Field, you have to use double quotes " --> "vf" in your expression

Comment: `@vf` references the *variable* the model input Vector Field (I named mine "`vf`") returns. Double quotes around it made no difference. `"vf"` does not work as there is no field literally named "`vf`".

Answer (score 4):

While I am not sure what the actual cause of trouble is (see below) I managed to solve it by using the `attribute()` function to get the field's value by specifying the field name as a string:

```
CASE
  WHEN attribute(@vf) = 'foo' THEN 1 
  ELSE 0
END
```

**Thoughts on the technical background**

I suspect it is something about the Vector Field output being an unquoted string and the Field Calculator is not recognising it as reference to a field. If I use `eval()` to eval a concatenated string of `"` + `field name` + `"` it works.

```
CASE
  WHEN eval('"' || @vf || '"') = 'foo' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```